# Android, run regular app in instrumentation mode (adb + debug only)

Tags: android, android-testing, android-uiautomator, android-instrumentation

I'd like to run an Android app in a way that it can access `InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation()` during the runtime.

This is only for debug builds and installing the app through ADB is sufficient. Because I don't want to use the instrumentation test-suite, I don't want to use `InstrumentationTestRunner` but launch the `MainActivity` of the app directly.

How is this possible?

What I've tried:

1. Added regular implementation dependency on test packages (instead of test only dependency) - worked

```
    implementation 'androidx.test.uiautomator:uiautomator:2.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0'
```

2. Added instrumentation to manifest

```
    <instrumentation android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:targetPackage="com.android.shell"
        android:label="App" />
```

(Not sure whether this is actually correct.)

3. Ran the app using (app already installed on the device)

```
adb shell am instrument -w com.example.app/.MainActivity
```

This results in:

```
android.util.AndroidException: INSTRUMENTATION_FAILED: com.example.app/com.example.app.MainActivity
    at com.android.commands.am.Instrument.run(Instrument.java:519)
    at com.android.commands.am.Am.runInstrument(Am.java:202)
    at com.android.commands.am.Am.onRun(Am.java:80)
    at com.android.internal.os.BaseCommand.run(BaseCommand.java:60)
    at com.android.commands.am.Am.main(Am.java:50)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.nativeFinishInit(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.main(RuntimeInit.java:399)
```

So essentially my question is, how do I achieve running the app in a way I can use `UiAutomator` during the runtime?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible:

**1.** Add the dependencies to your **build.gradle**. It should be like this:

```
implementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
implementation 'androidx.test.uiautomator:uiautomator:2.2.0'
implementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0'
```

**2.** Add the following **uses-library** inside `application` tag and **instrumentation** inside `manifest` in you **AndroidManifest.xml**:

```xml
    <!-- Add inside application tag -->
    <uses-library android:name="android.test.runner" />
```

Set `android:targetPackage` to your own application package name.

```xml
    <!-- Add inside manifest tag -->
    <instrumentation
        android:name="androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        android:label="App"
        android:targetPackage="com.example.app" />
    </manifest>
```

**3.** Create your activity. You can use `InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation();` there.

**4.** Create you Test class in the same source set of your application classes (inside **src/main/java**)

```java
    @RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
    public class Test {
        @org.junit.Test
        public void test() {
            // Put any code here. It is launching the activity.
            Instrumentation instrumentation = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation();
            Context context = instrumentation.getTargetContext();
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
```

**5.** Build and install the app.

**6.** Run the app using:  `adb shell am instrument -w -m -e debug false -e class 'com.example.app.Test' com.example.app/androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner`

**7.** (Optional) If you want to execute it directly from the `run` button in Android Studio, then add this inside `android` in your `build.gradle`, it will change the place where the test classes must be created, pointing to the same folder as the main code:

```
sourceSets {
    androidTest {
        java.srcDir 'src/main/java'
    }
}
```